# Setting up a date time

Tags: c#, date

I've been given an assignment by a friend for me to practise on C#. He wants me to set up a fitness counter, where he can add how many pushups/pullups etc he did, and then in a text file, print the date on which he entered that information (already done) and the amount of workout he did (already done). However, he also told me to set up a week and month system, where i will get everyday of his workout and print it as a whole in a weekly report, and then get all the weekly reports and print them as a month. I cant wrap my head around and find a way to approach this. How could i do it? Ive thought of getting each day from the file.txt and printing it out as a sum etc, but i cant find the appropriate code. Thanks a lot!
This is to get the day :

```
    DateTime localDate = DateTime.Now; 
    Console.WriteLine("The date today is " + localDate.ToShortDateString());
    Console.ReadLine();
```

And I've tried `DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;` etc but nothing

Comment: Show some code that you have tried

Comment: This is to get the day :          DateTime localDate = DateTime.Now;
            Console.WriteLine("The date today is " + localDate.ToShortDateString());
            Console.ReadLine();

Comment: And ive tried DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek; etc but nothing

Comment: you'll probably want to define the format of the lines/entries in your file.txt dataset

Answer (score 1):

What you can do for weeks is use the weeknumber. As there are different numbering systems, that isn't a property on 'DateTime' but is retrievable from a calendar. Use

```
CultureInfo ciCurr = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
int weekNum = ciCurr.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(DateTime.Now, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday);
```

For months, you can retrieve the month property of the date. Remember that with these rules, weeks do not add up to month and year totals, as weeks van span two months or years.